# CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state - error running flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, cocoapods

I have a problem running my flutter project. Here is the error I get.

[CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ9Rk.png)

This is my flutter doc

[flutter doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2xdz.png)

Everything looks fine. I have already tried:

- $ sudo gem install cocoapods
- adding a $PATH

Also I have closed and re-opened several times Android Studio and didn't work.

I have looked for every already opened thread on this topic but nothing worked.

Could you please help me out?

I am using last version of Flutter
Xcode 14

Thanks!!!

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Android Studio in Terminal

```
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried that but now it is giving me another error. I will open another thread as it is a different one.